# Are the Session Preview Database Credentials Required in Staging Website and OData Webservice?

Tags: session-preview

In order to allow fast-track publishing, I am assuming that the OData webservice requires the credentials for the Session Preview Database.

For the Content Delivery API to access the data within the Session Preview Database, at render time, the staging website also needs the Session Preview Database credentials.

Therefore I am assuming the Session Preview Database credentials are required in both places.

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and that's why in your cd_storage_conf.xml you'll find a section for the "WrapperDB". This is where you store the credentials for the session preview database.

```
  <Wrappers>
    <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
      <Storage Type="persistence" Id="sessionDb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
        <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
        <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
          <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
          <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
          <Property Name="databaseName" Value="##SESSION_PREVIEW_DATABASE_NAME##"/>
          <Property Name="user" Value="##SESSION_PREVIEW_USER_NAME##"/>
          <Property Name="password" Value="##SESSION_PREVIEW_PASSWORD##"/>
        </DataSource>
      </Storage>
    </Wrapper>
  </Wrappers>
```